# Django: How to pass object/object id to another template

Tags: django

I am new to the Django web framework.

I have a template that displays the list of all objects. I have all the individual objects listed as a link (object title), clicking on which I want to redirect to another page that shows the object details for that particular object.
I am able to list the objects but not able to forward the object/object id to the next template to display the details.

views.py

```
def list(request):
    listings = listing.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('/../templates/listings.html',{'listings':listings})

def detail(request, id):
    #listing = listing.objects.filter(owner__vinumber__exact=vinumber)
    return render_to_response('/../templates/listing_detail.html')
```

and templates as:
list.html

```
{% for listing in object_list %}
<!--<li> {{ listing.title }} </li>-->
<a href="{{ listing.id }}">{{ listing.title}}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

detail.html

```
{{ id }}
```

Comment: Please update your question with your urls.py. This is the file that maps URLs to your view functions.

Comment: @burhan I changed my href to have get_absolute_url but still when I click on it I dont get object.id displayed on the next page and then I have the detail views as def detail(request, id): l = list.objects.all(pk=id), render_to_response('..../templates/detail.html','l':l) But I am not able to get the id on that page. In models.py I have added def get_absolute_url(): return "/listings/%i" % self.id And finally my urls.py has url(r'^listings/(?P<id>\d+)',direct_to_template,{'template':'listing_detail.html'‌​}) Can you please tell me where and what's wrong that I am doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables that you pass in the dictionary of `render_to_response` are the variables that end up in the template. So in `detail`, you need to add something like `{'listing': MyModel.objects.get(id=vinumber)}`, and then the template should say `{{ listing.id }}`. But hat'll crash if the ID doesn't exist, so it's better to use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

Also, your template loops over `object_list` but the view passes in `listings` -- one of those must be different than what you said if it's currently working....

Also, you should be using the [`{% url %}` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) and/or `get_absolute_url` on your models: rather than directly saying `href="{{ listing.id }}"`, say something like `href="{% url listing-details listing.id %}"`, where `listing-details` is the name of the view in `urls.py`. Better yet is to add a [`get_absolute_url` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) to your model with [the `permalink` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator); then you can just say `href="{{ listing.get_absolute_url }}"`, which makes it easier to change your URL structure to look nicer or use some attribute other than the database id in it.

Comment: I changed my href to have get_absolute_url but still when I click on it I dont get object.id displayed on the next page and then I have the detail views as def detail(request, id): l = list.objects.all(pk=id), render_to_response('..../templates/detail.html','l':l)   But I am not able to get the id on that page. In models.py I have added def get_absolute_url(): return "/listings/%i" % self.id And finally my urls.py has url(r'^listings/(?P<id>\d+)',direct_to_template,{'template':'listing_detail.html'}) Can you please tell me where and what's wrong that I am doing

Comment: @nirvana Your problem is actually in your `urls.py` -- you're not calling your view function at all! Those `url()` calls associate a URL pattern to a view function, and you're actually using the `direct_to_template` "generic view" instead of the view you wrote. This also explains the name difference between `object_list` and `listings` that I mentioned above. You'll want to do `from my_app_name.views import detail` and then change `direct_to_template` to `detail`, and similarly with the listings page.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [@permalink decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator). It enables you to give your models generated links based on your urls pattern and corresponding view_function.

For example:

```
# example model
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=255, unique=True)
    #more model fields here

    #the permalink decorator with get_absolute_url function
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('example_view', (), {'example_name': self.name})

#example view
   def example_view(request, name, template_name):
        example = get_object_or_404(Example, name=name)
        return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

   #example urls config
       url(r'^(?P<name>[-\w]+)/$', 'example_view', {'template_name': 'example.html'}, 'example_view')
```

Now you can do in your templates something like this:

```
<a href={{ example.get_absolute_url }}>{{ example.name }}</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: He wasn't asking how to create the link, but how to retrieve the objects data fields in the details template.

Comment: @JamieForrest I changed my href to have get_absolute_url but still when I click on it I dont get object.id displayed on the next page and then I have the detail views as def detail(request, id): l = list.objects.all(pk=id), render_to_response('..../templates/detail.html','l':l) But I am not able to get the id on that page. In models.py I have added def get_absolute_url(): return "/listings/%i" % self.id And finally my urls.py has url(r'^listings/(?P<id>\d+)',direct_to_template,{'template':'listing_detail.html'‌​}) Can you please tell me where and what's wrong that I am doing

Answer (score 0):

In your detail method, just pass the listing into your template like so:

```
def detail(request, id):
    l = listing.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render_to_response('/../templates/listing_detail.html', {'listing':l})
```

Comment: I understood the question more as: 
How can I call my view from my template, passing the id selected as parameter?
Because, he has already passed a listing parameter in his first template call so I guess he knows how to do.